# CodeIgniter: When form data inserted to a table through an array, only "0" values are written in to the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

**Everything is working fine except, instead of writing the data on the form, it writes zeros. The table (new_reservation) looks like this after submitting some values:**

[image]

PK: res_id (AI, NN)

Not Null: All except "ext_bed"

**Model:** (reservations_model.php)

```
class Reservations_model extends CI_Model {

function add_reservations($data) {
    $this->db->insert('new_reservation', $data);
    return;
}

}
```

**Controller:** (reservations.php)

```
class Reservations extends CI_Controller {

function index() {
    $this->load->view('/main/new_reservation');
    $this->load->model('reservations_model');
}

function add_reservations() {       
    $data = array (
    'room_type' => $this->input->post('room_type'),
    'meal_type' => $this->input->post('meal_type'),
    'bed_type' => $this->input->post('bed_type'),
    'ext_beds' => $this->input->post('ext_beds'),
    'number_of_guests' => $this->input->post('number_of_guests'),
    'start_date' => $this->input->post('start_date'),
    'end_date' => $this->input->post('end_date'),
    'reservation_duration' => $this->input->post('reservation_duration'),
    'room_number' => $this->input->post('room_number'),
    'total' => $this->input->post('total')
    );
$this->reservations_model->add_reservations($data);
$this->index();
}
}
```

**View:** (new_reservation.php in /views/main folder)

```
<?php echo form_open('reservations/add_reservations'); ?>

<p>      
<label for="room_type">Room Type*: </label>
<select id="room_type"></select>
</p>

<p>      
<label for="meal_type">Meal Type*: </label>
<select size="1" multiple="multiple" id="meal_type"></select>
</p>

<p>      
<label for="bed_type">Bed Type*: </label>
<select id="bed_type"></select>
</p>

<p>      
<label for="ext_beds">Extra Bed(s): </label>
<input type="text" id="ext_beds" />
</p>

<p>      
<label for="number_of_guests">Number of Guests: </label>
<input type="text" id="number_of_guests" />
</p>

<p>      
<label for="start_date">Check-in Date*: </label>
<input  type="text" id="start_date" />
</p>

<p>      
<label for="end_date">Checkout Date*: </label>
<input type="text" id="end_date" />
</p>

<p>      
<label for="reservation_duration">Duration: </label>
<input type="text" id="reservation_duration" />(Nights)
</p>

<p>      
<label for="room_number">Room Number: </label>
<input type="text" id="room_number" />
</p>

<p>      
<label for="total">Total: </label>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="total" readonly="readonly" />
</p>   

<p>
<input class="btn" type="reset" />
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Check-in" />
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view

Use `name` not `id`

sample example from your code

```
<p>      
<label for="start_date">Check-in Date*: </label>
<input  type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form data.. they should have a name value ex:

```
<input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_data"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use name along with id, eg:

```
<input type="text" id="number_of_guests" name="number_of_guests">
```

for all the input statements

Answer (score 0):

get a value using name not by id

```
<input type="text" id="number_of_guests" name="number_of_guests">
```